# Crystal Report extracting only numbers from string field in database

Tags: crystal-reports-2010

i want to display only numbers from string field 
like:
AA
Gbj
mj
132
45
nn
8
io
9
 i want only 
132
45
8
9
how to get like this in crystal report.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the characters in the column and append to a string variable if the character is a number. Maintain a boolean var to store whether previous character was a number. If not add a space before a new character that is a number.